# POSTing data via axios without "wrapping" key?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, axios

I am trying to POST some data to an couchDB-Instance using Axios:

```
var payload = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2"
}
```

Posting to Couchdb:

```
axios.post("couchdb/testdatabase/", {
        payload
    })
    .then(function(response) {}
    )
    .catch(function(error) {}
```

On CouchDB, a Document like this gets created:

```
{
  "_id": "2b8f7ccc9216e6946ad2e06c16002fb1",
  "_rev": "1-50656bdcbb79f9b427c9aa5e0afb3255",
  "payload": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
```

}

**What i am trying to get instead, ist something like this:**

```
{
  "_id": "2b8f7ccc9216e6946ad2e06c16002fb1",
  "_rev": "1-50656bdcbb79f9b427c9aa5e0afb3255",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

Of course i could pass Key-Value-Pairs to the `axios.post()` method but with an bigger object that would be very time-consuming.

***So is it possible to remove that "payload wrapper" around those key-value pairs?***

Thanks

Comment: Yes, modify the object before your server returns it to your front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply remove curly brackets and pass it like that:

```
axios.post("couchdb/testdatabase/", payload)
.then(function(response) {}
)
.catch(function(error) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be wrapped in curly braces, try this:

```
axios.post("couchdb/testdatabase/", payload)
```

Or

```
axios.post("couchdb/testdatabase/", { key: 1, otherKey: 2 })
```